# second level nested inlines not showing in django-nested-inlines

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a nested admin interface using https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline **but the 2nd level is not showing up in the admin**...

I have a foreign key relationship between three models:

ContractTemplate => ContractClause => ContractSubClauses

(i.e. a template can have many clauses and every clause can have many sub-clauses)

**models.py**

```
class ContractTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class ContractClause(models.Model):
    contract_template = models.ForeignKey(ContractTemplate)
    title = models.CharField()
    ...

class ContractSubClauses(models.Model):
    contract_clause = models.ForeignKey(ContractClause)
    text = models.TextField()
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedStackedInline, NestedTabularInline


class ContractSubClauseInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = ContractSubClause

class ContractClauseInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = ContractClause
    inlines = [ContractSubClauseInline]

class ContractTemplateAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ContractClauseInline]

admin.site.register(ContractTemplate, ContractTemplateAdmin)
```

---

This is how the admin looks (first level - ContractClause - shows, but ContractSubClause(s) are not showing):

[image: admin]

What is missing to show the ContractSubClause(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I got the the same problem in the past and solved that now for me. Hope this also works for you.

It didn't depend on the different packages from soaa or silverfix. When I installed it with pip the package was insite PythonXX/Lib/site-packages, but somehow django wasn't able to use the package without throwing errors. So either set the system path to site-packages or copy the nested_inlines folder into Lib.